# Table border overlapping in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I know that IE doesn't apply css style to table rows, so I had to do a workaround where I added style to each cell instead. Now my problem is that in Firefox/Chrome, the outer border shows perfectly; but in IE it has gaps from the bottom border of the cell. This is what the difference looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rg8S.jpg  I cannot change the contents of the linked stylesheet and I cannot figure out what they are trying to say here [CSS Table cell border overlapping table border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051787/css-table-cell-border-overlapping-table-border)

Linked Stylesheet (style.css) contents:

```
body {
background-color: #cc0000;
}

.tablewhite{

border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tablewhite td{
background-color: #cc0000;;
color: #000;
font-weight: 10px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
padding-left: 2psx;
padding-right: 4px;
border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

HTML Page: http://pastebin.com/2mZYDx1n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a border onto your table:

```
.tablewhite{
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: There are conditions where the border is applied to only a few rows to mark them out and not the whole table, thats why I had used the row css.

Comment: If you leave the rest of your CSS the same, and add "border: 2px solid black;", as I have above, the border looks good to me on IE 8.. Let me know if you get different results.

Comment: That works, but there are times when I don't want to apply the border to the whole table - only some rows like here http://pastebin.com/2yFc2jPx Then I cannot use the border style for the table.

Comment: In your pastebin.com/2yFc2jPx example, what is the point of the ".newtable td {border: 1px solid white; }" code? Removing that makes table look nice in IE & other browsers

Comment: That is redundant, I was just testing something with it. But even without it, its the same for me in IE. Chrome/Firefox display the page perfectly, but in IE the white borders show on top of black. I tested this in IE 9, that probably is the issue. Maybe I need to get IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

```
.tablewhite {
    border-left: 1px solid #A3A3A3; 
    border-right: 1px solid #A3A3A3;
    background: #CCC;
}

.tablewhite td {
background-color: #cc0000;;
color: #000;
font-weight: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
padding-left: 2psx;
padding-right: 4px;
border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Try that and change the colors accordingly

Comment: With that the white border overlaps the black one in Firefox also. I want the black border to be on top of white, like it is in the Firefox image. Also, the problem is that I cannot modify the .tablewhite css as it is being used in a few other files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
body {
background-color: #cc0000;
}

.tablewhite{


border: 2px solid #000;
border-collapse: collapse;

}

tr {
    border-left: none !important;   
}

.left {
    border-left: none !important;   
}

.right {
    border-right: none !important;
}   

.tablewhite td{
background-color: #cc0000;;
color: #000;
font-weight: 10px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
padding-left: 2px;
padding-right: 4px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}



tbody {
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think its an issue with IE9